# How to disable a React button conditionally on a state value?

Tags: reactjs, button, state

I've added a simple form with one input and a save button. The save function is called and works as expected.

But I now want to add a boolean to disabled logic on the save button. So in my current page I have a state called `email` which I want to disable the button if this is empty.

What I did try is the following, passing `{!this.state.email}` into the disabled property of the button but it doesn't disable the save button. Similar to this [example](https://medium.com/@collardeau/to-react-from-jquery-disable-a-button-f5f6cc0ea885#.47zaticp5):

```
 <Button primary={true} disabled={!this.state.email} onClick={this._onSave}>Save</Button>
```

I also logged the value in the _onBlur method and I can see that email state is being populated.

Question:

How can you bind component state to button disabled property?

This is a gist of my current component:

http://hastebin.com/jufahijoza.js

Comment: Why are you using state like that? You shouldn't be using it like that. State should be used for the view. Just make a variable and set it to true or false based on when you need it. Then use a conditional statement to check if it's true or false.

Comment: And inside of the if statement disable/enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my comments for an explanation.

```
    _onBlur(event) {
       //if(true or false)
       // this.refs.myInputButton theres your button now disable/enable it with javascript

this.props.setUserEmail(event.target.value); 
            console.log(this.state.email);     
        }
```